# Flutter error: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
The getter 'key' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: key

The relevant error-causing widget was:
MaterialApp
file:///home/robert/flutter-ddd-firebase-course/lib/presenta
tion/core/app_widget.dart:20:14

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:notes_firebase_ddd_course/application/auth/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:notes_firebase_ddd_course/injection.dart';
import 'package:notes_firebase_ddd_course/presentation/routes/router.gr.dart'
    as app_router;
import 'package:notes_firebase_ddd_course/presentation/sign_in/sign_in_page.dart';

class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              getIt<AuthBloc>()..add(const AuthEvent.authCheckRequested()),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Notes',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder(router: app_router.Router()),
        theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.green[800],
          accentColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
          ),
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hello
I am working on Reso coder Domain Driven Design course [Flutter Firebase & DDD Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMiN59x3uH0&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iS5p-IezFFgqP6YvAJy84U&index=1)
All commits You can get here: [ResoCoder
/
flutter-ddd-firebase-course](https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-ddd-firebase-course/commits/master)

Episodes 1-7 was ok.
In episode 8 things get complicated.
I tried to fix it by checking commit by commit, some issues started in episode 8 with "injectable" package, so I updated pub and check ale commits from 9-th to 32-nd **one by one** and this error is there all the time.
In all these steps I:

- in buld.gradle set "minSdkVersion 26 and targetSdkVersion 30" (it helped)
- created example user in "authentication" section to make sure that data is there,
- created example row in firestore "section" in users and collection with "notes" subcollection to make sure that data is there,
- mantin pubspec.yaml file carefurly,
- run `flutter clean` command,
- flutter 'dev' channel

I am using:

```
Flutter 2.1.0-13.0.pre.288 • channel master •
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e384ca7979 (29 hours ago) • 2021-03-26 17:34:03 +0100
Engine • revision b5e15d055d
Tools • Dart 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-162.0.dev)
```

I did try older versions using fvm:

- 1.22.4
- 1.16.3

I checked author's code in separate directory on my local machine. There is the same issue. My project compails correctly only this exceptioin is thrown still. Probably there was some breaking change in dependencies and source code is outdated.